# Springboot Oauth2 : org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.DefaultWebResponseExceptionTranslator$UnauthorizedException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jackson, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to implement a fully functional Spring-boot oauth2. I manage to implement a login with success credential, I get the proper response with access_token and refresh_token, using `/oauth/token`

Using correct username and password

```
{
"access_token": "b8c45984-c573-4837-9ef6-6896f308a286",
"token_type": "bearer",
"refresh_token": "48145463-830e-4467-ab89-587bda6b32de",
"expires_in": 43199,
"scope": "read write"
```

}

and if i use a wrong username it give me a proper error, which i am happy about;

Wrong Username:

```
{error: "unauthorized", error_description: "No value present"}
```

error
:
"unauthorized"
error_description
:
"No value present"

but the problem comes when i use correct username and incorrect password; i get the below error

```
2018-05-28 14:47:25.264  WARN 6604 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : 
Failed to evaluate Jackson serialization for type [class     org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.DefaultWebResponseExceptionTranslator$UnauthorizedException]:
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name     'org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.OAuth2ExceptionJackson2Serializer': 
 BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; 
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' defined in class path resource
 [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: 
 Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate      [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor]: 
 Factory method 'transactionAdvisor' threw exception; 
 nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Any updates on this ? Were you able to resolve this ? If yes, request your help, I'm facing same issue.